# Lags data on Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, forecasting, sklearn-pandas

I'm using sklearn to make a forecast. Usually i will create lagged data to forecasting, this is easy if the feature only consist 1 column.

for example:

```
index  temperature
1      100
2      80
3      50
4      90
5      110
```

Usually i will create another column with shifting the temperature value to create lagged data using function like:

```
dataframe.temperature.shift()
```

So my dataframe become:

```
index  temperature temperature2 temperature3
1      100         NaN          NaN
2      80          100          NaN
3      50          80           100
4      90          50           80
5      110         90           50
```

Then when i want to forecast, i can fit using code like:

```
x = dataframe.loc[:,('temperature3','temperature2')]
y = dataframe.temperature
model.fit([x],y)
```

The problem is when i have a lot of column to create lag data, and need more lagged data for each column, my dataframe will be too big.

Is there any simple approach that i can use? Thanks!

For reference, this is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import talib

df = pd.read_csv('..\\data\\uj5.CSV', names=['date','time','open','high','low','close','volume'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date + df.time,format='%Y.%m.%d%H:%M')


# assuming this is the 'X', let say i need 100 lags of these column to predict the 'Y'
df['CDLBELTHOLD'] = talib.CDLBELTHOLD(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['CDLCLOSINGMARUBOZU'] = talib.CDLCLOSINGMARUBOZU(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['CDLDOJI'] = talib.CDLDOJI(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['CDLHIKKAKE'] = talib.CDLHIKKAKE(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['CDLLONGLEGGEDDOJI'] = talib.CDLLONGLEGGEDDOJI(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['CDLLONGLINE'] = talib.  CDLLONGLINE(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['CDLSHORTLINE'] = talib.CDLSHORTLINE(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['CDLSPINNINGTOP'] = talib.CDLSPINNINGTOP(df.open.values, df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values)
df['atr'] = talib.ATR(df.high.values, df.low.values, df.close.values,timeperiod=14)


#assuming this is the Y
df['target'] = #some int value
```

Comment: Maybe create a list of column's name then iterate through it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: the solution is not to create multiple columns with lag-n data, just dynamically create the intermediate values at compute-time.

Comment: Not in combination with scikit. When calling model.fit() you need to have your data ready (big dataframe as you said)

Comment: FSuyuti: please show us the computationa, already! You could use a matrix-multiplication formulation of the computation to pick up all the lag-k terms. Unless you state the question soon, this question already has gotten 4 Close votes and is likely to be closed. Which is a pity because I suspect you have an interesting computation, and the matrix-multiplication formulation would be neat and save lots of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use pandas here if you end up with a large matrix . Numpy is more appropriate here:

```
import numpy as np

x = you_data_frame.values
max_lag = 10 # number of lags you want to have 

m = np.array([])
for i in np.arange(len(x) - max_lag):
    new_row = x[i:i+max_lag][None, :]
    if len(m) == 0:
        m = new_row
    else:
        m = np.vstack([m, new_row])
```

then you cat fit your data using

```
model.fit(m[:, 1:], m[:, 0])
```

Comment: But ultimately if they don't need to store all the intermediate fields, dynamically generating them for the related expression sounds better.

Comment: @smci to use model.fit(..) you need to pass all the features and targets together

Comment: so you wrap extra code before the model.fit() call, to dynamically compute the intermediate lagged series. It might even be possible to frame the computation with all the lags it as multiplication by some matrix kernel. We don't know till we see OP's code.

Comment: How can i make this code to run in multiple thread or process? It run so long on one year data (about 75000 rows).

Comment: @F.Suyuti 75k row doesn't sound like something you would need multithreading for. But you can use [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and split the process on several parts of matrix m. If you keep vector x in the memory you won't have any dependences across the processes.

Answer (score -1):

So don't create multiple columns with lag-n data.

Only dynamically compute the lagged data when you need it. For example, it might even be possible to frame the computation with all the lags it as multiplication by some matrix kernel. We don't know till we see your code.
Show us your specific code or formula you're trying to compute if you want a more specific answer.

EDIT: to the downvoters, this is actually the more correct answer. If you clog up your dataframe with all sorts of intermediate and temporary columns, you will waste memory. On stuff you can dynamically compute as-needed. That's the wrong way to go. Same general principle as lazy-evaluation in Spark.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question to add the code, thank! :)